# Is it necessary to provide "Audio-only" stream when I use HLS(Http live streaming)?

Tags: ios, media-player, http-live-streaming

I read this document and I'm not sure I need to add audio only stream.
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1767/_index.html

App store review guideline was changed like following.

Video streaming content over a cellular network longer than 10 minutes must use HTTP Live Streaming and include a baseline 64 kbps audio-only HTTP Live stream
=> Video streaming content over a cellular network longer than 10 minutes must use HTTP Live Streaming and include a baseline 192 kbps or lower HTTP Live stream

When I have a audio-only stream, and user entered that stream, It looks bug, because there is still image. And It is little bit late recorvered from that stream.
So I just want to prepare minimum bitrate with video(video 100Kbps, audio 92Kbps).

Is it possible to use 192kbps video for minimum bitrate without audio-only bitrate?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because only apple can answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple basically moved the answer to that into the linked [Technical Note TN2224](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2224/_index.html).

> If your app uses HTTP Live Streaming over cellular networks, you are required to provide at least one stream at 192 kb/s or lower bandwidth. The low-bandwidth stream may be audio-only, or audio with a still image, but you should strive to have video in your 192kbps stream.

You should be fine now if your lowest stream is according to their restrictions and it must no longer be audio-only.